# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

my code just stopped working, and this errors occur

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ultimate_library.unified.showAll(unified.java:47)
    at ultimate_library.unified.<init>(unified.java:34)
    at ultimate_library.unified$8.run(unified.java:653)`

the code below doesnt have any error, i just dont understand is it not working, but sometimes it works but it sends this error "java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested"

```
public unified() {
    initComponents();
    DoConnect();        
    showAll();
    DoConnect2();        
    showAll2();
}

void showAll(){
   try{
   rss = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM accounts");
   while(rss.next())
   {
       String name = rss.getString("name");
       String email = rss.getString("email");
       String bdays = rss.getString("bday");
       loginModel.addRow(new Object[]{name, email, bdays});
   }
   }catch(SQLException err){
        System.out.println(err);
   }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new unified().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `the code below doesnt have any error` Why do I think, that this is not true? Maybe because of the mentioned exception? Which line is line 47 there?

Comment: loginModel.addRow(new Object[]{name, email, bdays});

Comment: So, you should think about why and when `loginModel` could be null.

Comment: i connected the loginmodel in the table which is connected to the database to display its value

Comment: Then read the JavaDoc of the method you're using there and check why it could return null.

Comment: So yea, if fixed it by rewriting the code/s that has been mention the error

Comment: Where is `stmt` initialized?

Comment: Don't do `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 0):

i found my mistake, instead of rss, i replaced it to rs2.

```
void showAll(){
   try{
   rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM accounts");
   while(rs2.next())
   {
       String named = rs2.getString("name");
       String emailss = rs2.getString("email");
       String bdayss = rs2.getString("birthday");
       loginModel.addRow(new Object[]{named, emailss, bdayss});
   }
   }catch(SQLException err){
        System.out.println(err);
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this solved your problem. Could you post more of your code?